# How force teamcity to use BTDF 6.0

Tags: biztalk, octopus-deploy, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-2016, btdf

We are upgrading from BizTalk 2013 R2 to BizTalk 2016. While we were in BizTalk 2013 R2, we used version Deployment framework for Biztalk 6.0(BTDF). but for BizTalk 2016, we need to have BTDF version 5.7.

And our current team city server has BTDF 6.0. As we are trying to build deploy our BizTalk 2016 code in teamcity, during the octopus deployment, we are seeing below mentioned error.

If possible, we would like to stick BTDF version 6.0, due license purchase problem and setting new server for that.

As I'm compiling the code in BizTalk 2016 with BTDF 5.7,  Is there a way to force our code to use BTDF 6.0 version during teamcity build and octopus deployment?

Or suggestions to achieve this goal?

**Error details**

```
2 additional lines not shown
June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info
/p:ENV_SETTINGS                "C:\Program Files (x86)\CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject\2.1.6\Deployment\EnvironmentSettings\Exporte... 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info
/p:BTSACCOUNT                  CorpCompany\BizTalkAccount                                                                   
June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info

June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info
################################################################################### 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info
Deploying BizTalk application CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject to the BizTalk console 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info
################################################################################### 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info

June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info
Deploying biztalk app CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject ....... 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info
Found shortcut for deploying app C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject 1.0\Deploy CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject.lnk 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:27Info
Executing command ... cmd  /c @echo on & cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject\2.1.6\\Deployment" & "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe" /p:Interactive=False  /t:Deploy /clp:NoSummary /nologo   /tv:4.0 Deployment.btdfproj /v:normal /p:DeployBizTalkMgmtDB=False /p:Configuration=Server  /p:ENV_SETTINGS="C:\Program Files (x86)\CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject\2.1.6\Deployment\EnvironmentSettings\Exported_ODSettings.xml" /p:BTSACCOUNT=CorpCompany\BizTalkAccount 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:28Info
Build started 6/3/2019 1:49:33 PM. 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Info
Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject\2.1.6\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" on node 1 (Deploy target(s)). 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Info
C:\Program Files (x86)\CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject\2.1.6\Deployment\Framework\BizTalkDeploymentFramework.targets(635,5): error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPathToDotNetFramework(Microsoft.Build.Utilities.TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.$(DotNetFrameworkVersion))". Must specify valid information for parsing in the string. Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).  [C:\Program Files (x86)\CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject\2.1.6\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj] 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Info
Done Building Project "C:\Program Files (x86)\CorpCompany.BT.CorpProject\2.1.6\Deployment\Deployment.btdfproj" (Deploy target(s)) -- FAILED. 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Info
Build FAILED. 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Info
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.20 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Info

June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Info
################################################################################### 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Info

June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Info
cmd completed with exit code 1 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Error
run-command : Script cmd failed. see log for errors 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Error
At C:\Octopus\Work\20190603204924-32036-322\Library_PublishBTDFBiztalkApplication_636951665673032401.psm1:734 char:9 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Error
+         run-command "cmd" $arg 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Error
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Error
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Error
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,run-command 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:29Error

June 3rd 2019 13:49:31Fatal
The remote script failed with exit code 1 
June 3rd 2019 13:49:31Fatal
The action BizTalk - Deploy Application on DevServer failed
```

Comment: what does git have to do with that?

Comment: So what is the error in the C:\Program Files (x86)\[Application name] for BizTalk\1.0\DeployResults\DeployResults.txt on the remote server?

Comment: There are no licensing issues with BTDF.  What are we missing?